# Has there ever been a game-winning/tying drive that started with less than 13 seconds?

Tags: american-football, nfl, history, records, field-goal

In the January 23, 2022 NFL Divisional playoff game between the Kansas City Chiefs and Buffalo Bills, the Chiefs trailed 36-33 in the 4th quarter when they started a drive at their own 25-yard line with only 13 seconds left in the game. Two pass completions and two timeouts later, they kicked a 49-yard field goal as time expired to send the game to overtime.

What is the NFL record for least amount of time left that a game-winning or game-tying drive started with? The drive must have started after a kickoff or a punt. I'd be interested in both FG and TD drives.

Comment: Just for some clarity, what qualifies as a "drive"?  For example, if a team recovered a fumble on the other team's 10 yard line with :01 remaining, is that a drive?  And does only a FG count, or can a touchdown also count?  Does it need to be scored by the offense, or can it be scored by the defense or special teams?

Comment: For one example - would this qualify?  (It's not actually shorter, though it easily could have been, given the only play was a kneel down): https://www.espn.com/nfl/playbyplay/_/gameId/400874495

Comment: This question is really about how quickly an offense can move the ball. I already saw on the list of [hail maries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hail_Mary_passes_in_American_football) the 2010 JAX/HOU game (a drive starting with 8 seconds after a fumble) and the 1987 SF/CIN game (a drive starting with 2 seconds after a 4th down stop). So I will say the drive must start after a kickoff or punt.